# iOS 7- storing multidimensional NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults: iPad crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsarray

We have a multidimensional NSMutableArray stored in NSUserDefaults. We update array based on index value and update the userdefaults. Everything works fine, but, we face this weird issue

> -[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

this happens only in iPad 7.1 iOS. It works in iPhone 7.1 iOS, iPad, iPhone 8.0 iOS and above.

Declaring and initializing array

```
self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.dataId]];
```

This is what we have been doing,

```
- (void)writeDataWithName:(NSString *)name andAnswer:(NSString *)answer {
    for(int i=0;i<self.dataArray.count;i++) {
        NSMutableArray *tempMutable = [self.dataArray mutableCopy];
        if([tempMutable[i][0] isEqualToString:name]) {
            tempMutable[i][1] = answer;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tempMutable forKey:self.dataId];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes at this line of code

```
tempMutable[i][1] = answer;
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  The exception is pretty clear, but why not look into CoreData instead of abusing NSUserDefaults?

Comment: The exception is on a call replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:, so its someplace other than the posted code.

Comment: @Paulw11 It works in most of the devices except in iOS 7 iPad, iPhone it works pretty well. Storing little data on CoreData is lots of overhead. It is a multidimensional array just because of the structure involved

Comment: `tempMutable` is a mutable copy of `self.dataArray`, but `mutableCopy` doesn't make a deep mutable copy, so the arrays *inside* `self.dataArray` won't be affected. Based on your exception `tempMutable[i]` contains a `NSArray` not an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, but it just works in iOS 7 iPhone with the same code, works without a problem for iOS 8 and above. Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: Your code is flawed - It doesn't account for the fact that the internal arrays returned by `objectForKey` will also be immutable.  The fact that it works on some versions is luck.  You need to iterate `self.dataArray` making mutable copies of the inner arrays, however, looking at your code it seems that you would be better storing a dictionary in NSUserDefaults - that way you could avoid the loop and the multi-dimensional array

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. It worked